# how does cloudera Impalad instance works?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, cloudera, impala

I am using cloudera impala where i have started statestore on one machine and imapalad instance on all the machine node. how does each instance of imapalad and statestore knows about all other impalad instance for distributing the load when querying. I have set the configuration but no where i am specifying the list of data node for them to kno.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statestore(running as `statestore`) does the following:

1. Checks the health of all nodes in the cluster, and continuously relays the information to all demons(`impalad`)
2. Only one statestore is enough.
3. If no `statestore` is avaliable the demons still work, but the cluster becomes less robust.
4. When the `statestore` comes back online, it re-establishes the connection with the other nodes and resumes its monitoring function.

Comment: how does each impalad knows about the other impalad location cos that is required to distribute the query among all the impalad..

Answer (score 0):

For infromation on how dose Impala works see [this](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Impala/latest/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_concepts.html)

If you want to balance load among the impala instances you can do that by introducing load balancer.

Comment: Where is the data allocated in impala？

Comment: @johnsam i dint got your quetsion "Where is the data allocated in impala?" please elaborate..